# Missing chess-workshop-symbols package with latest skak under Texlive

Tags: texlive, chess, skak

I have just done an upgrade of my Texlive 2017 (Windows) and skak was one of the packages that was updated (now version 1.5.3). However the chess-workshop-symbols package is no longer present.

Does anyone know why it was deleted or is this a bug? Where is the package now?

Thanks.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chess-workshop-symbols}

\begin{document}

Test.

\end{document}
```

This worked before the update. Now it gives an error that chess-workshop-symbols is not found. The file was previously in the latex\skak directory but now it's gone.

Comment: Show a minimal example which can be used for tests.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Please see the update.

Comment: You don't need the package. All (imho) commands it provides are already defined by chessfss (loaded by xskak) and the package does nothing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the update. Of course I can avoid the error by copying the file to my local tree but I was trying to work out why the file is missing. Your suggestion looks like a good solution.

Comment: Probably Torben removed it as it has no use todays.