# using lyx chess workshop symbols two Knight goes to the same

Tags: symbols, chess

if i have two Knight in the b colum, one in b8 and one in b4, how distinguish which one goes to c6, I try N8c6 but that is not working

this is the Latex configuration

```
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{chess-workshop-symbols} 
\smallboard 
\columnsep 0.25in 
\columnseprule 0.4pt 
\hyphenpenalty 10000
```

this is the document,

```
\begin{multicols}{2}

Mainline: 1. e4 d5 2. exd5 Nf6 3. d4 Nxd5 4. c4 Nb4 5. Qa4+ N8c6

[centered board]

KnightMove: b8->c6

Gambito Evans aceptado

Mainline: 6. d5 b5 7. cxb5 Bf5 8. Na3 Qxd5

[centered board]

Las negras tratan de buscar el enrroque, las blancas se lo impediran.

Mainline: 9. bxc6 Qe4+ 10. Be3 Nd3+ 11. Bxd3 Qxa4

[centered board]

sacrificio de torre aprovechando temas tácticos de ataque descubierto y amenaza de mate

Mainline: 12. Bxf5 Qa5+ 13. Bd2 Qxf5 14. Nf3 Qe4+ 15. Be3 Qb4+

[centered board]

Partida agresiva del estilo romántico del ajedrez

\end{multicols}
```

Comment: Your question is not answerable. You should export a minimal example and show the code. Btw:  the sty chess-workshop-symbols no longer exists, it has been removed from the skak package.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415581/missing-chess-workshop-symbols-package-with-latest-skak-under-texlive

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: Your code snippets are not a minimal example: they can not be compiled. A minimal example should start with \documentclass, end with \end{document} and it should contain all the latex code.

Answer (score 2):

Using N8c6 or N4c4 to distinguish the knights works fine for me. Be aware that the package you mention has been removed from the skak-package. This could mean that your tex system is quite outdated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{skak}

\tinyboard 
\begin{document}
\newgame

\mainline{1. e4 d5 2. exd5 Nf6 3. d4 Nxd5 4. c4 Nb4 5. Qa4+ N8c6}

\showboard

\newgame
\mainline{1. e4 d5 2. exd5 Nf6 3. d4 Nxd5 4. c4 Nb4 5. Qa4+ N4c6}

\showboard

\end{document}
```

[image]